# Convert perl associative array to PHP array

Tags: php, perl, code-generation

Is there a php library I can use to convert an associative array in perl to an associative array in php ? If not, is there any recommended way of doing this ? Regular expressions ? A bunch of explode and implode calls ?

I want to go from

```
my %arrayname = (
    key1 => "Value1",
    key2 => "Value2",
    key3 => "Value3",
...
```

to

```
$arrayname = array(
        "key1" => "Value1",
        "key2" => "Value2",
        "key3" => "Value3",
```

Comment: I think you mean `$arrayname = array(…)`. Also, you're basically trying to parse Perl source code into PHP?

Comment: good catch, thanks.. will fix that now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have Perl on your server, you use:

```
print 'Array(';
while (($key, $val) = each(%arrayname)) {
    print "'$key' => '$val',";
}
print ');';
```

You can also have a look at the [PECL Perl package](http://pecl.php.net/package/perl), this library integrates a Perl parser in PHP.

You can use [an online Perl interpreter](http://codepad.org/zyL3oh4U) with example code and working (there is just one extra comma at the end).

I created a regex that almost works. You can try it, but it depends on the structure of the Perl array:

```
preg_match_all(#\%(.+)\s=|\n(.+).*#);
```

Example data:

```
my %arrayname = (
    key1 => "Value1",
    key2 => "Value2",
    key3 => "Value3"
)
```

You can test it with the [Regular Expression Test Tool](http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/).

Comment: +1 definitely agree it's easier to produce source in a foreign language than it is to parse a foreign language's source.

Comment: Perl is not an option in this case, I'm parsing someone else's perl config files from PHP.

Comment: @sjobe: sure does suck to be stuck on Microsoft's chain, doesn't it?

Comment: @tchrist I never knew that php was also from M$, now it all makes sense :P

Comment: @sjobe: The point is that only Microsoft systems neglect to include Perl; all others have it, and even Prisoners of $Bill can get it easily enough. It is completely unreasonable to expect to parse Perl using anything but perl, and that remains true no matter what. It is also provably impossible. So do the easy thing, not the impossible one.

Comment: @tchrist true, but all I need to parse/convert is a couple of associative arrays, nothing else. There are only so many ways an associative array in perl can be represented, parsing them into any language should not be that bad.. just don't want to re-invent the wheel

Comment: @sjobe It is **not true**, from a theoretical point of view, that there are only so many ways to represent the contents of an associative array in Perl. There are infinitely many ways, although I leave it to you to figure out whether that’s ℵ₀, ℵ₁, or worse. In  your discrete case, the possibilities may be more limited, but we have no way of knowing that because the problem space has not been sufficiently well defined or even described.

Comment: @tchrist I promise all the arrays look EXACTLY like the sample code I posted, I'm not trying to invent Perl2PHP 1.0 or something :D

Comment: @infinity Thanks, I think regex is what I'm going to use, when I test the one you posted on the link though, my output is 

Array
(
    [0] => %arrayname =
    [1] => arrayname
)

Comment: @tchrist Yes, it does sometimes suck to be on Microsoft's chain, especially when you run to sysadmin's who'd rather waste developer time and twiddling your thumbs time on really expensive problems rather than install Perl.