# Guidance in front end and back end desiging

Tags: php, html, perl

I am making a database and a corresponding website for the same. The website offers taking (scientific) queries from the user and searching the information (protein/nucleotide sequences, name of organism, accession id, etc.) against my database as an output.

I am done with the database and the website, even the script (HTML->PHP->Perl) fetches information asked by the user.

**My Problem**

Let's take for example, a database with Employee info like ID, name, age, sex, etc.

I have all the output information in an array. The problem is when I have to post it into a html output. The thing is, I can print these values like printing the **complete html file** with the respective **tags** and then opening the html file, but my web page has some buttons/options which will do something (here, print any info, drawing charts using the values like age, salary,etc.). It will also have a scroll function for displaying the information and the buttons on the bottom of the page.

So I need some basic guidance,

- Should I go with dynamic pages or static?
- If dynamic, is there any way I can parse the arrays from Perl to PHP?

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154333/convert-perl-associative-array-to-php-array?rq=1 for your question about Perl arrays in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

If it's in a database, I'd go dynamic. But I don't understand why you're jumping between perl and PHP, either can do the job on it's own.

If your data is being queried into arrays in perl, parse it out into JSON or XML. Both perl and PHP have awesome parsing modules available.